# How to overload the power function (^) in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm tring to implement a following datatype:

```
data Inter = Inter Double Double deriving (Read, Eq)
```

and I implemented `(+)`,`(-)`,`(*)` and `(/)`,
but the potentiation to a integer power`(^)`should not be repeated multiplication for this datatype.
Is there a way for me to implement this function just like i did to the others?

Comment: Looking at [the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#%5E), if you've already implemented the `Num` instance, then `(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) -> a -> b -> a` comes automatically. You cannot redefine it for a particular type because it's not part of any typeclass.

Comment: You cannot overload it, since it is not a method of type class.  but you still can implement your own version `(^)` operator by hiding `(^)` from `Prelude` using `import Prelude hiding ((^))` in the module you define it.

Comment: @assembly.jc would you need to use -XNoImplicitPrelude then?

Comment: My opinion: if your operation is not repeated multiplication, then it should not be called `(^)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner It could be repeated multiplication, but with a faster implementation (e.g. if `*` is idempotent). Or in an AST datatype you may want to represent powers with a separate constructor, and I think it still makes sense to use `(^)` for this case.

Answer (score 2):

`^` defined in prelude you can't overload it. It doesn't belong to any typeclass.

It is defined using `*` from `Num`.

See [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#%5E).

Answer (score 2):

Considering that your implementation of `(^)` will be an optimization and *will* produce equivalent results, what you can do is define your faster version in the same module as your `Num` instance and call it say `interPower`. Then you can try adding some rewrite rules, which in theory should fire, but I'd suggest compiling a test program with `-ddump-simpl-stats` and confirming that they do indeed fire before the rules from `base` do:

```
interPower :: Integral b => Inter -> b -> Inter
interPower = ...
{-# INLINABLE [1] interPower #-}

{-# RULES
"Inter^2/Int"     forall x. (x :: Inter) ^ (2 :: Int) = interPower x (2 :: Int)
"Inter^3/Int"     forall x. (x :: Inter) ^ (3 :: Int) = interPower x (3 :: Int)
"Inter^4/Int"     forall x. (x :: Inter) ^ (4 :: Int) = interPower x (4 :: Int)
"Inter^5/Int"     forall x. (x :: Inter) ^ (5 :: Int) = interPower x (5 :: Int)
"Inter^2/Integer" forall x. (x :: Inter) ^ (2 :: Integer) = interPower x (2 :: Int)
"Inter^3/Integer" forall x. (x :: Inter) ^ (3 :: Integer) = interPower x (3 :: Int)
"Inter^4/Integer" forall x. (x :: Inter) ^ (4 :: Integer) = interPower x (4 :: Int)
"Inter^5/Integer" forall x. (x :: Inter) ^ (5 :: Integer) = interPower x (5 :: Int)

"Inter^Int"       forall x y. (x :: Inter) ^ (y :: Int) = interPower x y
"Inter^Integer"   forall x y. (x :: Inter) ^ (y :: Integer) = interPower x y

  #-}
```

**Edit**

Just tried above approach and it indeed overloaded the usage of `(^)`:

```
print (x ^ (2 :: Int))
print (x ^ (3 :: Int))
print (x ^ (4 :: Int))
print (x ^ (5 :: Int))
print (x ^ (6 :: Int))
print (x ^ (2 :: Integer))
print (x ^ (3 :: Integer))
print (x ^ (4 :: Integer))
print (x ^ (5 :: Integer))
print (x ^ (6 :: Integer))
```

resulted in these rules to fire when compiled with `ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl-stats -ddump-to-file`. See `main.dump-simpl-stats`:

```
...
1 Inter^2/Int
1 Inter^2/Integer
1 Inter^3/Int
1 Inter^3/Integer
1 Inter^4/Int
1 Inter^4/Integer
1 Inter^5/Int
1 Inter^5/Integer
1 Inter^Int
1 Inter^Integer
...
```